# Tomcat startup time

Tags: apache, tomcat, embedded-linux, yocto

I've installed tomcat 9 on an imx6 dual core , with SC CARD. ( yocto ) 
Startup time is about 6 minutes, which does not make sense. 
Is there anything I need to do to port this version to ARM ? could it be that File System operation is taking too long ( due to SD CARD ) ? 
It seems like jar scanning is running in the background

Answer (score 0):

6 minutes seems too long. Anyway, if you don't want to scan your JAR files, you can edit catalina.properties file like this:

```
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=*
```

This will considerably improve the startup time.